# Constructing dual variety using duals of singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $X\subset\mathbb P\mathbb C^n$ be a closed, irreducible (reduced) variety. Then the dual variety $X^*$ can be defined as the projection of the closure of the conormal variety
$$
\mathrm{Co}(X)=\{(x,H)\in X_{sm}\times (\mathbb P^n)^*\colon T_X(x)\subset H\}
$$
onto the second factor, where $X_{sm}$ is the set of smooth points of $X$ and $T_X(x)$ is the tangent space at $x$. In general it is not clear what happens exactly if you close $\mathrm{Co}(X)$.

Is anything similar to the following statement true?
Let $Y\subset X$ be the set of all singular points of $X$ and assume $Y$ is non-degenerate, i.e not contained in any hyperplane, and let $Y^*$ be its dual.
Do you get $X^*\subset Y^*\cup\pi_2(\mathrm{Co}(X))$? So you get all points of $X^*$ that come from the closure of $\mathrm{Co}(X)$ also from $Y^*$.

Or is there a different way to understand $\mathrm{clos}(\mathrm{Co}(X))$ using tangent spaces of singular points?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a closed, irreducible (reduced) variety. Then the dual variety $X^*$ can be defined as the projection of the closure of the conormal variety
$$
\mathrm{Co}(X)=\{(x,H)\in X_{sm}\times (\mathbb P^n)^*\colon T_X(x)\subset H\}
$$
onto the second factor.."

**Answer:** I do not have a precise reference but I believe the "variety" $Co(X)$ can be defined as the zero scheme $Z(\phi)$ of a certain map

$$\phi: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$$

of locally free finite rank sheaves on $X \times_k \mathbb{P}^n$.

**Question:** "Or is there a different way to understand clos(Co(X)) using tangent spaces of singular points?"

**Amswer:** It involves the "jet bundle" $J^l(L)$.

Comment: This answer looks reasonable. Does anyone know why it was flagged as "not an answer"?

Comment: @user1729 Boh...very strange events happen to me too. +1